# Ruby on Rails Active Records issue

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

The models in question are:
User  Followed

The "followeds" schema(or table) has "user_id" that is a reference to "users" table
And it has "followed_id" that is an integer.

What I want to achieve:
Inside my controller I want to select all the users that have an id corresponding to `followed_id`
Something like

```
def index
  @users = User.all.where(something like =>  "user.id: followeds.followed_id")
end
```

Basically comparing the id for users table (user.id) to followeds.followed_id integers and if they match extract the record of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model you should have:

```
# No idea what's the nature of the relationship between your models, but
# pick one of these two
has_many :followeds, foreign_key: :followed_id
has_one :followed, foreign_key: :followed_id
```

then in your query call:

```
User.joins(:followeds) # or :followed if apply
```

Comment: Do we need to use `:foreign_key` in `has_many :followeds, foreign_key: :followed_id` and `has_one :followed, foreign_key: :followed_id`? Looks like standard name convention

Comment: Not sure what you meant. That's the way [to set foreign keys](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-foreign-key) when they are different that the name of the model.

Comment: I meant that OP said *The "followeds" schema(or table) has "user_id"*. It means user just `has_many :followeds`, no need to use `:foreign_key` here

Comment: @mechnicov yes, but the OP not only have a relation between the models with the `user_id` but also with `followed_id` and that's the key the OP want to use in their query.